# Configurable product with group product functions

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, configurable-product, php, grouped-products

I'm looking for a way to do the following.

From a single product, the user would select from the dropdown a height (for example 100 and 200)

Once the dropdown is selected a table fills in with different products as per group product does allowing users to select different qtys from these listed products

Comment: Looking for any information, even if it's can't be done.

Comment: Also posted here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/744798/ but still having issues trying to find any information on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use a grouped product for this. On the frontend add a custom dropdown that filters the grouped product displaying the ones that are applicable and hiding the rest. 
Although this will require some (perhaps a lot) of javascript you can still use default Magento functionality for the backend and order items handling.

Another option would be to use a configurable product but this will limit you to displaying a dropdown to the user with the products